# addEventListener and attachEvent

Tags: javascript

I'm using this piece of code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // Hide the address bar
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```

but IE doesn't understand `addEventListener`- it needs `attachEvent` which seems to give an error in Chrome. How can I check if this method is supported and then serve the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", myFunc, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", myFunc);
}
```

Comment: isn't window.attachEvent('onload', func)?

Comment: @stecb Yep, it is `onload`.